# Arduino 2 times slower? Broken?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, infrared

Hello I have been here for a couple hours troubleshooting code and turns out it wasn't even my code that was the problem. My arduino uno is like 2 times slower than what its supposed to be. If I blink a led with a delay of 500ms it takes 1 second. I was using it last night and it was working just fine. I am working on a remote of sorts and the IR led was going retartedly slow. So then I switched it to my backup, still didn't work. Then digitalWrite showed me it was 2 times slower than it should be. I haven't done anything to it besides the following: (Flashed it around 100 times since i got it). I've only had it for like a month so I would appreciate if someone could tell me what I could do to fix it :/

Comment: Do you have the right board selected in the menu? Is serial still working at the correct baud rate?

Comment: My programmer is set to "AVRISP mkil", board is set to "Arduino uno". And I have used 19200 in Serial.begin before and its possible that I tried to flash it as a esp8266 but yeah.. That's about it :/

Comment: If you `Serial.print()` something, is that received correctly in your Serial Monitor with the same baudrate used in the sketch?

Comment: @chrisl I can't tell the speed but if I set the serial monitor to 9600 and Serial.begin(9600) I can see it fine it seems.